# Correct way to Integrate JAX-RS with CDI?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, quartz-scheduler

I used to integrate Service and DAO beans in Jersey REST resources by annotating them with `@Path` following [Java EE tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced004.htm)

> In general, for JAX-RS to work with enterprise beans, you need to annotate the class of a bean with @Path to convert it to a root resource class. You can use the @Path annotation with stateless session beans and singleton POJO beans.

So my code used to be something like this:

```
@Path("/")
public class ServiceResource {
   @Inject
   private AccountService accountService;

   @GET
   @Path("/account/get")
   public Account getAccount(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
     return accountService.get(id);
   }
}

@javax.inject.Singleton
@Path("")
public class AccountService {
   public Account get(String id){...}
}
```

Now, I started integrating a Quartz Job into my application, and I wanted to find a way to inject my `AccountService` inside a job like this

```
public class AccountJob implements Job {
  @Inject
  private AccountService accountService;

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {
    accountService.updateAllAccounts();
  }
}
```

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467074/using-cdi-in-quartz-jobs/23522906#23522906) that tells to use `DeltaSpike` to do the Job, so I added the following dependencies to my `pom.xml`, and without adding any more lines of code to any class the inejection of `accountService` to my `Job` works fine

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>deltaspike-scheduler-module-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>deltaspike-scheduler-module-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl</groupId>
    <artifactId>deltaspike-cdictrl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl</groupId>
    <artifactId>deltaspike-cdictrl-weld</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

**However**, I realized that when I remove the `@Path("")` from `AccountService`, its instance is still injected fine inside `ServiceResource`, so my questions are the following:

1. Why adding `DeltaSpike` dependencies made it possible to inject my beans without using `@Path` on them?
2. By searching more, I understood that `DeltaSpike` internally uses `Weld` to do the injection, and since I am already using `GlassFish 4.0`, I know that `Weld` is already there, so why the injection is not working by default in my `Job` class and in `ServiceResource` class without adding `@Path` on my beans? Actually why adding `@Path` is even suggested in the Java tutorial?
3. Is there any bad side effects that I don't see in my code, because I think that I am mixing multiple DI methods here without really understanding how do they work?

**Update:** After more search, I realize that `Jersey` doesn't use `Weld` for dependency injection, instead it uses `HK2`, a different framework that also happens to be a part of `GlassFish`, when I try to inject `AccountService` without using `@Path` it shows the following exception

> org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=**AccountService**,parent=**ServiceResource**,qualifiers={}...

So this updates the questions to the following:

1. How to make `HK2` injections works?  // Without using `@Path` as mentioned in the Java EE Tutorial
2. If I managed to to do `DI` with `HK2`, will it be safe to use `DeltaSpike` to do `DI` for the Quartz Job? Is it okay to mix two CDI framewroks together to scan the classes and do the injection?

I put my my source code on pastebin; `pom.xml` is [here](https://pastebin.com/fcjsZuC7) and the `Java` is [here](https://pastebin.com/9FS4nxUQ)

Comment: Did you consider using EJB timers instead of Quartz?

Comment: Just wanted to say that yours is a very well written question, and it's a pity that it has so few upvotes just because it is more _niche_ (compared to other lower quality but higher score questions).

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to set the `Path` annotation on your `AccountService` CDI bean. If CDI is enabled on your application (either with empty beans.xml in CDI 1.0 or discovery-mode=all in CDI > 1.0), you can `@Inject` any CDI bean in your JAX-RS resource.
So you just have to write the following class:

```
@Path("/")
public class ServiceResource {
   @Inject
   private AccountService accountService;

   @GET
   @Path("/account/get")
   public Account getAccount(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
     return accountService.get(id);
   }
}

@javax.inject.Singleton
public class AccountService {
   public void Account get(String id){...}
}
```

The article you linked in your post deals with mixing EJB and CDI annotations. For example you can mix `@Stateless` and `@Path` annotations. It's interesting for example because you can :

- Benefit of EJB transaction in your Rest resource (even if now you can use `@Transactional` interceptor binding)
- Set a pool of resources
- etc.

Note that all of this works without the help of deltaspike dependency.

For your second question, as Quartz manages its own threads, classes are not handled by CDI so you can not inject beans in Quartz classes. The aim of the deltaspike module is to allow injecting CDI beans in Quartz Jobs. Internally, deltaspike controls CDI Contexts.

**EDIT**

For your last questions:

- Your HK2 problem comes pretty sure from a missing dependency (in your application or server). As said in a previous comment, I managed to deploy your App on Glassfish 4 (build 89) with the source files you provided.
- Regarding the integration of CDI with Quartz, I think the best is to implement your own `JobFactory` and instanciate your jobs using `BeanManager`. Take a look at this link : https://devsoap.com/injecting-cdi-managed-beans-into-quarz-jobs/

Comment: @Roulibot, I have empty `beans.xml` in my project, but If I don't have `@Path` on my beans, I always get an exception like this `org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=AccountService ,parent=ServiceResource,qualifiers={},position=-1 ....`

Comment: @Roulibot, also after some search about this exception, I realize that `Jersey` uses `HK2` not `Weld` to handle CDI https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/ioc.html

Comment: @fujy : Adding the `jersey-gf-cdi-ban-custom-hk2-binding` dependency should solve your problem.

Comment: @Roulibot, thanks for the effort, but adding this dependency also didn't fix it, I am still getting the same exception of `hk2`.

Comment: @Roulibot Could it be related to the way that I am annotating the `AccountService`  with `@javax.inject.Singleton`

Comment: Can you try adding   following dependency :  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
    </dependency>  ?

Comment: @Roulibot Didn't work either, still the same exception

Comment: @Roulibot  I put my my source code on pastebin if you can check what is the issue with it, `pom.xml` is [here](https://pastebin.com/fcjsZuC7) and the `Java` is [here](https://pastebin.com/9FS4nxUQ)

Comment: @fujy : I successfully deployed your app on Glassfish 4. Here is the version : `Version = GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (build 89)`. Here is the outpur : `New Account with Id = 3`. Your problem must come from server (configuration or version)

Comment: @Roulibot I tried with GlassFish 4.0 (not sure about the build) on Windows, and still getting the same exception.

Comment: @Roulibot So I found that I had `beans.xml` with `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"` instead `bean-discovery-mode="all"`, it is fixed now, even without adding `jersey-cdi1x`. Thanks for the help, I upvoted your answer, but the second part of my question is still unanswered, should I use `DeltaSpike` to integrate `Quartz` Job? Is it safe to mix 2 `CDI` scanners? What about I just use `DeltaSpike` without `HK2`?

Comment: when you managed to deploy it, did you add `bean.xml` descriptor to the project? if yes,what is the `bean-discovery-mode` that you applied?

Comment: I applied `all` mode.

Answer (score 1):

First of all injected resources(beans) **and Jersey Endpoint class(point of injection)** must be CDI-Aware. It must be detecteable by CDI. We can use bean-discovery-mode="all" - then CDI scan ALL classes  or 
bean-discovery-mode="annotated" and MARK our class with PROPER annotation: from here : [Bean defining annotations](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#default_bean_discovery). I prefer@Dependent or @RequestScoped

Then we must use Jersey Extension

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>{version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

`

to connect CDI with HK2 discovery mechanism.
Here is  [Official oracle Guideline](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced004.htm)

Answer (score -1):

The default beans.xml discovery-mode (in Java EE 7) is "annotated".  Which means only beans that have CDI annotations are recognized and managed by CDI.

Your AccountJob class is not annotated.  If you want CDI to be able to inject the service into it then you need to annotate it with some scope annotation, e.g. @ApplicationScoped.

Your other option is to create CDI producer for creating AccountJob beans.  See:
http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_producer_methods

Comment: A Quartz Job instance is supposed to be instantiated by  `QuartzInitializerListener` instance. Annotating it with a `CDI` annotation will create another instance of it that will make the "Quartz Job" injectable in other classes!, which is a wrong practice

Comment: And the same thing goes for the producer method

Comment: Not true on the producer method.  There is no reason the producer method couldn't look up the Quart Job and then return the same instance.