# Injecting a @Named bean into Jax-Rs Class

Tags: jax-rs, cdi

I am trying to inject a @Named bean into a jax-rs resource class. But when i try to accountBc object it is always null.

What should i do to inject the accountbc into BuildController?

```
@Named
@Path("/build")
public class BuildCotroller {

    @Inject
    @Named("AccountBcImpl")
    private AccountBc accountBc;


    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public AccountDto getBuilding(@QueryParam("buildId") Long buildId) throws BaseException {
        return accountBc.getAccountByBuildId(buildId);
    }
}
```

AccountBcImpl class

```
@Named("AccountBcImpl")
public class AccountBcImpl extends AccountBaseBcImpl implements AccountBc {
```

Comment: @Named is cdi, not jsf.

Comment: Java-ee is too broa and with a plain java jdk this cannot be reproduced. So not 'java' related either

Comment: @Kukeltje You are being extremely helpful, thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Are you using an EE server?

Comment: I am using Weblogic server

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028589/correct-way-to-integrate-jax-rs-with-cdi it contains relevant info. But is answered in a weird way that it is not a full duplicate (even the downvoted answers contain relevnt info)